# Number theory question maximum possible difference between $a$ and $b$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

$1287a
45b$ is a 8-Digit number, where $a$ and $b$ are not zero. The number is divisible by 18. What is the maximum possible difference between $a$ and $b$?

My solution: I first said since it's divisible by 18, it's also divisible by 9 and 2, and since its divisible by 9, the sum of its digits is divisible by 9 so $$a + 27 + b $$ is divisible by 9. Now how do I carry on?

Comment: You mean divisible by $9$ not $18$ in the last line - what is the condition for divisibility by $2$?

Comment: $b$ has to be even

Comment: So $b$ has to be $2$,$4$,$6$ or $8$, and $a+b+27$ has to be divisible by $9$.Then check which option has the highest difference between $a$ and $b$

Comment: Just skip the $27$ since $a+27+b$ divisible by $9$ means $a+b$ divisible by $9$ because $27$ is already divisible by $9$.

Comment: OK, I'm still stuck.

Comment: The only two numbers generated by two digits that are divisible by 9 are 9 + 9 = 18 and 7 + 2 = 9, but you already know it must be even so a and b can't both equal 9 and one must be ever (i.e. a = 7, b = 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done most it. Also, $b$ is even, and $9 | a+b$. And we need to maximize $a-b$ therefore, taking the largest possible $a$ and minimum possible $b$, we get $7-2 = \boxed{5}$ as $a,b \not=0$.

Comment: how do you know the maximum value for a is 7?

Comment: If $a$ is greater than 7, ie if $a= 8$ then $b = 1$ which is odd.Therefore, not possible. If $a = 9$ then $b = 0$.Not possible again.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. a=1, b=8 gives a difference of 7.

Answer (score 0):

The eight digit number is divisible by 18=2.3^2.  We therefore need it to be

(i) divisible by 2, and

(ii) divisible by 9

(i) gives us that b is even

(ii) gives us that its digital sum is divisible by 9.  The digital sum is 27+a+b, and with 27 divisible by 9 we thus have a+b divisible by 9.

Finally,the question requires that

(iii) "a and b are not zero".

If we interpret (iii) as "both of a and b must not be zero" then the optimum solution is 9, with a=9, b=0.

If we interpret (iii) as "neither of a nor b must be zero" then the optimum, solution is 7, with a=1, b=8.